# how to go to previous screen

Tags: asp.net

I am using two kinds of buttons, on button takes the user to the next screen. Here I am using a session variable to take the user to the next screen:

```
protected void Buttondocumentdetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Narration"] = TextBox2.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/TJFAQ0001.aspx", false);
}
```

This is working properly -- after clicking this button the user is sent to the next screen, which is is "TJFAQ0001.aspx".  On this page I am using button to take the user to the previous screen:

```
protected void previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Narration"] =null;
    Response.Redirect("TJFAQOO1.aspx", false);
}
```

This is working, but all the data has been cleared.  I want the same data when I click previous button.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect.

You can pass the page field data in a context variable and then pass it to the next page. When redirected to the previous page pass this back and do the necessary processing and then fill the data back to the controls.

Do not use Session variable in this context. You can add a context variable when using Server.Transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repopulate the data in TJFAQOO1.aspx page when it gets loaded on click of previous button as it is a new get request and postback kind of facility is not available.